# A good way to add a different background image for each page?

Tags: hooks, widgets, post-thumbnails, pages, child-theme

I'm working an a [Thematic](http://themeshaper.com/thematic/) child theme wherein I need to have a unique image decorating each of the site's main pages, from a pre-defined set of permanent images. It would also be ideal to have one of these same images randomly selected to appear on all other pages.

Using a sidebar widget to load the images seems like a good option, but I don't know how to create my own widgets yet, and haven't had any luck finding a plugin which provides the simple functionality I'm looking for. I also don't want to clutter up the admin panel with plugins and options that the client shouldn't be fiddling with.

I think it will probably be most ideal to put something into my `functions.php` which adds some generated markup to a Thematic hook based on the page ID, but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing, so I thought I should ask to see if someone already has a great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at their [demo](http://themeshaper.com/demo/thematic/?page_id=69) source, the easiest way to do this is by styling page classes like `pageid-69` or `slug-example-page`:

```
body.slug-example-page{
  background: url(...);
}
```

If it has to be random image, add your styles in the header template so you can use PHP to generate dynamic css.